# How to identify lines, starting point and ending point of each line in a floor plan using opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, straight-line-detection

I am creating a tool to generate 3d model of a house by analyzing its floor plan. Up to now i was able to isolate all the wall of a floor plan.

Original Floor Plan :-
[image]

Isolated Walls :-

[image]

Then I tried applying hough transformation to identify lines and its corresponding coordinates. But the problem is identified lines are all vertical lines.

After drawing all the detected lines into the floor plan :-

[image]

After reducing number of lines drawn to the image :-

[image]

You can clearly see that all the lines are vertical.

What i actually want is to identify all the lines and each of its starting point and ending point.

[image]

Comment: the issue is in your code. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: seems like you only selected vertical lines from the Hough transformed representation. So there is some bug in your code.